# MSTest doesn't find updates in tests

Tags: visual-studio-2010, unit-testing, mstest

I have a Visual Studio 2010 test solution where I am using MSTest.  I will be adding multiple test projects for different components in the future.  Recently, when I added a new test project (the first time I've added a test project to the solution since the original test project), I have noticed a strange problem.  Whenever I add new tests or modify existing tests in the new project and try to do a "Rebuild Solution", Visual Studio says "Rebuild All Succeeded", but the changes aren't reflected in the Test Results.

I can get the changes to take effect by Rebuilding the specific project, but it's just weird that a Rebuild All doesn't take effect in my added project.

I can tell that the changes aren't taking effect, because I used the above method to build a working test, then added a line to throw an Exception in the test, did a "Rebuild Solution", then watched the test still pass.

This isn't a major issue, but it would be nice to know how to fix it, since I will be doing testing in this pattern for a long time to come.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I felt like a total dunce when I figured this one out.

In the Configuration Manager, I forgot to check the Build box for the added project, so the solution didn't know to build it when I did a rebuild all.